# Error in sed command in terminal

Tags: csv, sed, terminal, command, syntax-error

I go into terminal and I put in this command:

```
sed 's/X(Y)Z/A/g' filename.csv > newfile.csv
```

Trying to replace `X(Y)Z` with. I think the parentheses around the Y might be complicating things.

This is the error I get: RE error: illegal byte sequence.

Please let me know what I can do.

Comment: Your command, as written, works fine for me.

Comment: You'll need to add info about what shell you're using, what type of system you're on, etc. Your command works for me on a couple different systems.

Comment: Hey, I am using bash and am on a Mac Pro 2015. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to coding!

Comment: sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence

Comment: Try prefixing your `sed` command with `LC_ALL=C ` and  a space like this `LC_ALL=C  sed  's/.....`. Then try running the command `locale` to see your locale settings.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, sorry it did not work. Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that your file `filename.csv` contains non-ASCII (probably Unicode) characters and your `sed` is expecting ASCII.

The first thing to do is to examine the file and see if that is the case. I think you can do that with:

```
cat -vet filename.csv
```

and you will probably see highlighted characters that are non ASCII. Alternatively you can use `iconv` to try and convert it to ASCII and see if it gives an error because there are non-ASCII characters in there.

If there are non-ASCII characters in there (like accents and non-english characters and some times smileys, apostrophes and quotes), you either need to tell `sed` that they are there, or remove the *unhappy* characters if you don't really need them.

To see what `sed` is expecting, you need to run `locale` and paste the output into your original question by clicking `edit` underneath it. Then you may need to change your locale to make `sed` happier about Unicode like I suggested in the comments.

Hope that helps!